# Falha na sincronização? MyWorkBench 6.3 --> phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boas pessoal, gostava que me esclarecessem uma dúvida e se possível, me ajudassem.
Eu elaborei um modelo de dados (myWorkBench) e depois sincronizei o modelo de dados.. 
Após isso, tenho acesso às tabelas no phpMyAdmin mas não sei porquê, falta lá uma tabela.. alguém me pode explicar o porquê?
Isto porque estou a tentar inserir dados através do phpMyAdmin e está-me a dar um erro.
Aguardo colaboração.

Algumas imagens :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, nos informe a mensagem de erro para analisarmos melhor, porém tem diferença de versão pois cada um vai interpretar as palavras reservadas de formas diferentes devido a versão.

Comment: Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gaf`.`participacoes`, CONSTRAINT `fk_participacoes_alunosTurmas1` FOREIGN KEY (`participacaoAlunoId`, `participacaoTurmaId`) REFERENCES `alunosturmas` (`alunoTurmaAlunoId`, `alunoTurmaTurmaId)